# Remove specific tekst within XML Tag in datagridview c#

Tags: c#, xml, gridview, dataset

I have this example-row of an XML file.

-< InstallationEx >

< connectionstring >Data Source=192.168.1.2;Initial Catalog=F052051;Persist Security Info=True;User 
  ID=sa;Password=beanie;< /connectionstring >

< datadir >\\192.168.1.2\data\xmo\< /datadir >

< enabled >true< /enabled >

< longname >Beanie< /longname >

< mtime >2017-08-17T10:29:45.0404315< /mtime >

< name >F052051< /name >

< platform >test< /platform >

+< groups xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" >

< version >8.38< /version >

< /InstallationEx >

And this is the code that I have en my application to show data in gridview.

```
public Connectionstring()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        constringview.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml("http://10.10.62.104/xmoads/3.0/installationsex?_token=D21E34A5-21E4-405B-9EDE-18A99A8FD2CA&format=xml");
        ds.Tables[0].Columns[0].ColumnName = "ConnectionString";
        ds.Tables[0].Columns[1].ColumnName = "Ip Adresse";
        ds.Tables[0].Columns[3].ColumnName = "Kliniknavn";
        ds.Tables[0].Columns[5].ColumnName = "Installationsnummer";
        ds.Tables[0].Columns[6].ColumnName = "Systemtype";
        RemoveColumns(ds.Tables[0], ds.Tables[0].Columns[2], ds.Tables[0].Columns[4]);
        ds.Tables[0].Columns[1].SetOrdinal(2);


        constringview.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        constringview.RowHeadersVisible = false;
        kundeCount.Text = "Antal fundne installationer: " + constringview.Rows.Count.ToString();



    }
```

Is it possible programable to remove characters in the < datadir > XML-tag in the gridview so that it's only the IP adress that is shown? And how?

I've tried all kinds of searches on google to get a solution on this, but nothing usefull though :(

Comment: the IP address is part of the innertext of the xml.  So be way is to add a new column to the DataTable for just the IP.  the parse the connectionstring column to get the new IP column.

Comment: Could you add an example on how to do that?

Comment: You could simplify your code : DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex you can do something like this

```
sing System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
             DataTable dt = new DataTable();
             dt.Columns.Add("IP", typeof(string));
             string pattern = "Data Source=(?'ip'[^;]+)";
             foreach (DataRow row in dt.AsEnumerable())
             {
                 string connectString = row.Field<string>("ConnectionString");
                 Match match = Regex.Match(connectString, pattern);
                 string ip = match.Groups["ip"].Value;
                 row["IP"] = ip;
             }
         }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot =)

Had to write it a little different, bcause i'm working with a dataset and not a datatable =)

Comment: You could simplify your code : DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];